# Drop event not happening

Tags: javascript, html

With this code the drag message is shown but not the dropped message. When I drag the first element is not visually dragged but the dragstart event is triggered

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
        <body>
            <section draggable="true" id="origen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; border-color: green; border-style: solid;">origen</section>
            <section draggable="true" id="destino" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border-color: blue; border-style: solid;">destino</section>

            <script>
                window.addEventListener("load",carga);
                var origen = document.getElementById('origen');
                var destino = document.getElementById('destino');

                function carga(e){
                    origen.addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.dataTransfer.setData("Text",origen.outerHTML);
                        console.log("dragstart");
                    },false);


                    destino.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        //origen.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                        console.log('dropped');
                    },false);
                }
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cancelling the dragstart event with `e.preventDefault()`, that's why the element is not being dragged.

You must, however, instead cancel the `dragover` event of your drop target in order to allow other elements to be dropped onto it. (More information on why that is the case can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations))

```js
window.addEventListener("load",carga);
var origen = document.getElementById('origen');
var destino = document.getElementById('destino');

function carga(e){
    origen.addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        e.dataTransfer.setData("Text",origen.outerHTML);
        console.log("dragstart");
    },false);

    destino.addEventListener('dragover',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    destino.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //origen.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        console.log('dropped');
    },false);
}
```

```html
<section draggable="true" id="origen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; border-color: green; border-style: solid;">origen</section>
<section draggable="true" id="destino" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border-color: blue; border-style: solid;">destino</section>
```